# When do I need to create Apple Developer Account?

Tags: iphone, ios, developer-program, app-store-connect

Say I want to start working on some app X which I want to submit to App Store.

Is it necessary to have a developer account, *before* I can start working on this app?

Answer (score 5):

A free Apple Developer Program membership now allows you to develop apps and test them on your devices. A paid membership allows distribution.

<strike>A developer account is *not* required to start developing apps, however not having a developer account whilst developing the app can have the following downsides:</strike>

- You will **not** be able to build the app on a **real device** ([unless you jailbreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-real-iphone-device/4180498#4180498)).
- You will **not** have access to the **latest** developer builds of iOS and Xcode, or their **documentation** (a free account will only allow access to the latest *public* builds and their documentation).
- You will **not** have full access to the Apple Developer Forums (a free account will allow this for certain sections).
- You will **not** be able to create **provisioning profiles** for services such as PhoneGap Build.

As per above, certain features are accessible with a free Apple Developer Account. You can sign up at [Apple Developer Registration](https://developer.apple.com/programs/).

Comment: Note that a free developer account will allow the first and third (I am not certain about the last)

Comment: @Mark When I log in to my free developer account, and I change the Scheme to iOS Device, it tells me that it's unable to build & run to that device because I need a provisioning profile, which I can't get... Is this just because I have two accounts or something else?...

Comment: @Mark: Does the `Organizagion/Company` enrollment (https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/standard/) type also have this free account?

Comment: @user2054339 AFAIK it wouldn't matter since the difference between Personal and Company is only for features that you'd not be able to access anyway... (i.e. iTunes Connect)

Comment: and then how does one create this free account?

Comment: @user2054339 [Apple Developer Free Registration](https://developer.apple.com/register/index.action)

Comment: hey grgarside, that's what I was interested in, if I register for this free account now, can I upgrade later to the Organization/Company enrollment type?

Comment: @user2054339 Yes you can - when signing up for the full paid account, it will ask you which account type you would like.

Comment: To add to @mark's first comment, the free developer account will not allow you to create provisioning profiles, therefore you will not be able to run your application on a device, only in the simulator

Comment: This is no longer true as of Xcode 7. See http://9to5mac.com/2015/06/10/xcode-7-allows-anyone-to-download-build-and-sideload-ios-apps-for-free/